# elm: define subscription port with no parameters

Tags: elm, elm-port

Is there a way to define a subscription port with no parameters in Elm?

Something like:

```
port updateTime : () -> Sub msg
```

With this code, I'm getting the error that "Port 'updateTime'  has an invalid type"

With the code:

```
port updateTime : (String -> msg) -> Sub msg
```

It's working but I don't need to send nothing from the javascript function to Elm.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The closest you can get is probably something like this: Create the port similar to your examples but with the first parameters as `(() -> msg)`:

```elm
port updateTime : (() -> msg) -> Sub msg
```

Assuming you have an `UpdateTime` `Msg` that accepts no parameters,

```elm
type Msg
    = ...
    | UpdateTime
```

You can then tie into the `updateTime` subscription like this:

```elm
subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    updateTime (always UpdateTime)
```

Now, on the javascript side, you'll have to pass `null` as the only parameter.

```js
app.ports.updateTime.send(null);
```

**Update for Elm 0.19**

In Elm 0.19 you had to be explicit about which Elm modules exposed ports, so you may have to update your module definition to include `port module`.

```elm
port module Main exposing (main)
```

Comment: This works. But I wonder why there is no documentation about this on the official site? I was looking on the https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/javascript.html#ports but there I couldn't find something about how to achieve my task (also no mention about always)... and it sucks... no books about ELM and incomplete documentation...

Comment: Yeah, it sucks that this isn't documented--I had to read Native to find out how that was called. If you're ever unsure, you can try to jump into the guts of the runtime. Note: Elm not ELM.

Comment: I might have messed something up, but does this work for 0.19?

Comment: Yes, this still works with Elm 0.19. [Here is a working example](https://ellie-app.com/66ZgNqYn2J2a1). The only real difference is that you have to define the module as `port module` at the top